Reassign an Approval in Power Automate
For my organization, I use a Power Automate flow to grab data submitted by Microsoft Forms to create Approvals that go to a range of folks.
When I create the Approvals using the "Start and Wait for Approval" action, I set the requestor as the person that submitted the Form. But presumably, I am still the "created by" for these Approvals.
The flow sends the Approval requests randomly (actually in a round-robin, not random) to one of the members of a committee.
Occasionally, for one reason or another (e.g. the assigned person may have gone on vacation or is for some reason unresponsive), an Approval needs to be reassigned to another person.
he problem is that I do not see the created Approvals in my list of Approvals in Teams, nor in the Approvals tab (Sent) of Power Automate. Further, when I use Power Automate Dataverse action to List rows in Approvals or Approval Requests tables, I do not see recent Approvals - only the ones I created when testing the flow, i.e. the ones I assigned to myself.
Can I use Power Automate to retrieve and reassign an Approval using the assigned to and date created?
